# How to do a hg update or clone in one line of bash?

Tags: bash, mercurial

I am looking for an option to do an hg update on a repository or to clone it if it doesn't exist. So the command has to fail only if something went wrong (clone or update).

That has to work in `bash`, preferably if you have the `set -e` already configured.

Comment: Not `hg` specific, but... why do you need it to be in one command? `A || B` should do the right thing and fail only if both `A` and `B` fail. (to clarify, something like `hg update || hg clone <source>`)

Comment: Make it an answer! Still I would like not to see any errors in the output when the command succeeds. Still, seeing them when it fails is highly desired.

Comment: I don't get the question, can you please explain? `hg update` is _usually_ executed _from within_ the repo, e.g. `~/src/myproj$ hg up`. `hg clone`, on the other hand, is executed when _there's no repo yet`, as in `~/src$ hg clone http://server/myproj myproj`. How do you envision your combined command to be called? Where?

Comment: Actually agree with @Helgi here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The disjunction operator in bash, `||`, can do this scenario: try first command, if it fails try second command, if *that* fails return the error code. Specific to this question,

```
hg update || hg clone <source>
```

would try the update; if it fails, it would try to clone. If cloning fails, the whole line exits with clone's error code.

> I would like not to see any errors in the output when the command succeeds.

Why should there be errors when the command succeeds?

You can kill the output by `>/dev/null`; you can kill the errors by `2>/dev/null`; whether on each component separately, or by enclosing the whole line in parentheses and putting redirection after.

Answer (score 3):

```
cd <directory> && hg update || hg clone <source>
```

If the cd fails because directory doesn't exist, then the hg clone is run from the correct directory level.